# NSXMLParser: EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: swift, nsxmlparser

I'm newish to Swift, and not a regular coder anymore so apologies, chance are I'm missing something obvious!

I have an NSXMLParser class that is giving me a EXC_BAD_ACCESS fault when attempting to add a result item to an array.

I believe (using Xcode debugger) that I have a valid Security (my result class) instance.

My result array is empty and I'm attempting to append the first item when I get the error.

The class is below:

```
class YahooXMLParser: NSXMLParser, NSXMLParserDelegate{

    var results: [Security] = []
    var parser: NSXMLParser = NSXMLParser()

    var xSecurityTicker: String = String()
    var xPurchasePrice: String = String()
    var xLatestPrice: String = String()
    var xStopLossPrice: String = String()
    var xChange: String = String()
    var xProfitPercent: String = String()
    var eName: String = String()

    func parseYahoo(url: NSURL) ->[Security]{
        parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: url)!
        parser.delegate = self
        parser.parse()
        return results
    }

    // NSXMLPArser Delegate functions

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        eName = elementName
        if elementName == "col0" {
            xSecurityTicker = String()
        }
        if elementName == "col1" {
            xLatestPrice = String()
        }
        if elementName == "col4" {
            xChange = String()
        }
    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String?) {
        let data = string!.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
        if (!data.isEmpty) {
            if eName == "col0" {
                xSecurityTicker += data
            } else if eName == "col1" {
                xLatestPrice += data
            } else if eName == "col4" {
                xChange += data
            }
        }
    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
        if elementName == "row" {
            let newSecurity = Security(ticker: xSecurityTicker,
                latest: NSString(string: xLatestPrice).floatValue,
                change: NSString(string: xChange).floatValue)

            results.append(newSecurity)
        }

    }

}
```

My newSecurity values are:

---

newSecurity XMLTest.Security    0x00007f863b7368d0  0x00007f863b7368d0

securityName    String  ""

securityTicker  String  "HSX.L"

purchasePrice   Float   0

latestPrice Float   861

stopLossPrice   Float   0

profitPercent   Float   0

change  Float   29

---

If there isn't an obvious error what else should I be looking for to find the fault?

Thanks.

Comment: In which line do you get the error?

Comment: results.append(newSecurity)

Comment: Smells like one of those awful compiler bugs. Try a `println` right before the `append` and see what `result` contains.

Comment: Thanks - The println helped. Still not sure why but results wasn't properly accessible. Despite Xcode debugger showing it as "([XMLTest.Security]) 0 items" - which I thought meant it was, correctly an empty array of Security items.  Adding an initialiser for 'results = []' at the start of parseYahoo() solved it.  The initialiser at the start of the class should have done the same thing shouldn't it?

Comment: The debugger itself needs debugging. I often found it does not display the correct values. Obj-C did behave much better here.